# Check List lenght in rdlc report

Tags: c#, vb.net, list, reporting, rdlc

I'm passing a dataset to a report using an object data source. The data source contains object of a custom class. This class have a list of nested object.

I need to output the value of 3 of these objects or `String.Empty`. So if the list contains 'A' and 'B', the report should output 'A', 'B' and ''.

I print the value of the object in the list like so:

```
=Fields!MyList.Value(0).ObjectPropertyToPrint
```

However, if the list doesn't contains 3 items, I have `#Error`.

I've tried this way

```
=iif(Fields!MyList.Value.Length >= 2,Fields!MyList.Value(2).ObjectPropertyToPrint,"")
```

and

```
=iif(Fields!MyList.Value.GetUpperBound(0) >= 2,Fields!MyList.Value(2).ObjectPropertyToPrint,"")
```

But both results in `#Error`

I also tried to output only

```
=Fields!MyList.Value.Length
=Fields!MyList.Value.GetUpperBound(0)
```

But both printed `#Error`

This is the C# List object I'm using. It's only a workaroung to pass nested object to rdlc

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObjectList : List<MyObject>
{
    public MyObjectList () { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issue using the following line:

```
=if(Fields!MyLisValue.Count() >= 2,Fields!BolProducts.Value(1).ObjectPropertyToPrint,"")
```

Notice the use of `if` instead of `iif`. Since `iif` is a function, all argument are evaluated   . This cause an index out of range and crash.